# When i select the option , i need the selected value and the <td> id to display in <div> from any row

Tags: jquery

When i select the option from table row, I need to display the selected value and the `<td>` ID in `<div>`(x and y) for any row.
But i am able to do it from the first row only. When I select from second row, it doesnt work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testselid").change(function(){
        var v1 = $(this).val();
        $("#x").html(v1);
    });
});
</script>
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td id="testid">data1</td><td>data1</td>
        <td>
            <select id="testselid">
                <option hidden="true" >select</option>
                <option value="1">one</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
                <option value="3">three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="testid">data2</td><td>data2</td>
        <td>
            <select id="testselid">
                <option hidden="true" >select</option>
                <option value="1">one</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
                <option value="3">three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="testid">data3</td><td>data3</td>
        <td>
            <select id="testselid">
                <option hidden="true" >select</option>
                <option value="1">one</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
                <option value="3">three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID name should be unique. thats the problem here. I use class here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".testselid").change(function(){
  var v1 = $(this).val();
  $("#x").html(v1);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
  <td id="testid">data1</td><td>data1</td>
  <td>
      <select class="testselid">
    <option hidden="true" >select</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
         </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="testid">data2</td><td>data2</td>
        <td>
         <select class="testselid">
    <option hidden="true" >select</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
       </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="testid">data3</td><td>data3</td>
     <td>
       <select class="testselid">
          <option hidden="true" >select</option>
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
       </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have same id for every select tag, id must be unique, so it works only for the first select tag, change id to class and change in your jquery #testselid to .testselid:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".testselid").change(function(){
     var v1 = $(this).val();
        $("#x").html(v1);
   });
  });
```